creating range map doppler
I'm trying to create a range doppler map for a chirp signal which has the following parameters:
pri = 5e-6;
pw = 2e-6;
CPI = 0.5e-3;
B = 100e6;
f_c = 40e9;

for one single target which located at 400m with velocity of 100 m/s.
unfortunately, I'm not getting the excepted result.
here is my code:
%% defining parameters
pri = 5e-6;
pw = 2e-6;
CPI = 0.5e-3;
B = 100e6;
f_c = 40e9;
f_s = 200e6; % sampling frequency
N_s = round(pw * f_s); % Number of samples based on the sampling frequency
number_of_pulses = round(CPI / pri);
c = physconst('LightSpeed'); % speed of light

%% defining t axis and h(t)
t = linspace(0, pw, N_s); % Time vector covering the duration of the pulse
h = exp(1i .* pi .* (B / pw) .* (t - 0.5 * pw).^2) .* (t >= 0 & t <= pw);

%% location and velocity
R0 = 400;
V = 100;

%% baseband signal
t_for_whole_CPI = (0:number_of_pulses*pri*f_s-1)/f_s;
time_delay_for_whole_CPI = 2*(R0+V*t_for_whole_CPI)/c;



s_RX_baseband = zeros(1, length(t_for_whole_CPI));
for n = 0:number_of_pulses-1
    t_n_CPI = t_for_whole_CPI-n*pri;
    s_RX_baseband = s_RX_baseband + ...
    exp(1i * pi * (B / pw) * (t_n_CPI - time_delay_for_whole_CPI - 0.5 * pw).^2) .* ...
    exp(1i * 2 * pi * f_c * (t_for_whole_CPI - time_delay_for_whole_CPI)) .* ...
    exp (-1i*2*pi*f_c*t_for_whole_CPI) .* (t_n_CPI - time_delay_for_whole_CPI >= 0 & t_n_CPI - time_delay_for_whole_CPI <= pw);
end

%% arrange the recieved signal in a matrix
rows = number_of_pulses;
columns = round(f_s*pri);

s_RX_baseband_reshaped = reshape(s_RX_baseband, [columns, rows]).'; %transpose because reshape fills columnwise. in our result - number of rows: CPI (number of pulses), number of columns: number of samples per PRI

%% matched filter

s_RX_filtered = zeros(size(s_RX_baseband_reshaped, 1), size(s_RX_baseband_reshaped, 2));
ref_signal = h;

for n = 0:number_of_pulses-1
    s_RX_filtered(n+1,:) = conv(s_RX_baseband_reshaped(n+1,:), conj(fliplr(h)), 'same');
end

%% FFT
doppler_matrix_fft = fftshift(fft(s_RX_filtered, [], 1), 1); % performing FFT on the first dimension (column)

%% creating doppler map

range_resolution = c / (2 * f_s); % Range resolution
range_axis = (0:columns-1) * range_resolution; % Calculate range axis
doppler_bins = size(doppler_matrix_fft, 2);
velocity_axis = linspace(-number_of_pulses/2, number_of_pulses/2-1, doppler_bins) * (c / (2 * CPI * f_c));
figure;
imagesc(range_axis, velocity_axis, 20*log10(abs(s_RX_filtered)));

figure;
imagesc(range_axis,velocity_axis, 20*log10(abs(doppler_matrix_fft)));
xlabel('Range [meter]');
ylabel('Velocity [meter/sec]');
title('Range-Doppler Map');
colorbar;

I'm excepting to see a map in which there is cross centered by (400, 100) but that's not what I get, for some reason I'm getting that the velocity is -100 m/s.
Thank you!


Haven't taken too deep a look at this, but you're definitely not simulating your target returns correctly. Specifically, you're not simulating the Doppler shift on each return, hence why you get a velocity of zero. I would also re-examine how you're using the convolution function (try doing a full convolution) and how you're determining your range axis.

@Envidia Thank you for your response! I understand now that I didn't performed the baseband correctly. I should multiply by the negative exponent term (I've edited the code), but for some reason velocity looks like -100 and not 100. In addition, By performing a full convolution I'm getting out of range error. Do you have any idea how can I know what are the "important" indexes that I should take from the filtering operation (matched filtered)? Thanks a lot.

The RDM will capture whether or not the target is moving towards or away from the radar. If it's moving away, the Doppler frequencies will be negative, so you need to determine that. Also, recall that the full convolution will give you negative time delays, which aren't used in processing since you can't look into the future, so you must use the positive delays only.

@Envidia Thanks! last question please: can you please help me  with understanding how should I define the range resolution?

Theoretical range resolution is typically defined as the distance between the half-power points of an ideal IPR, which works out to be $0.886 c_0 / (2B)$ for the unapodized monostatic case. When apodization is used, $0.886$ increases accordingly.

@dopp_11 The RDM itself will have range resolution cells that are sized to $c/(2f_s)$ where $f_s$ is your sample rate. The achieved range resolution of separating two targets is $c/(2B)$ if using the Rayleigh bandwidth definition, which is normal practice for radar systems.

The following is quick and dirty, but hopefully it helps:
% Radar, signal, and simulation parameters.
c0 = 3e8;
pri = 5e-6;
pw = 2e-6;
CPI = 0.5e-3;
B = 100e6;
f_c = 40e9;
fs = B * 1.25;

% Function that will return the DC sample of a vector.
dcsample = @(x) x( floor(length(x)/2) + 1 );

% Define the waveform.
Nsamp = floor( pw * fs );
pw = Nsamp / fs;
t = ( 0 : Nsamp - 1 ) / fs;
t = t - dcsample(t);
wfm = exp( 1j * B / pw * t.^2 );

% The pulse times.
Npulse = ceil( CPI / pri );
txmt = ( 0 : Npulse - 1 ) * pri;
txmt = txmt - dcsample(txmt);

% The range and delay to the target on each pulse.
tgtrng = 400 + 100 * txmt;
tgtdelay = 2*tgtrng/c0;

% How long we sample for.
Wrng = 1000;
Trcv = 2*Wrng/c0 + pw;
Nrcv = ceil( Trcv * fs );
trcv = ( 0 : Nrcv - 1 ) / fs;
% trcv = trcv - dcsample(trcv);

% The frequency sample locations.
f = ( 0 : Nrcv - 1 ) * fs / Nrcv;
f = f - dcsample( f );

% Pad the waveform out to Nrcv samples, transform
% to the frequency domain, apply linear phase ramp
% to shift to the desired ranges, and transform
% back to the time domain. This gives us the waveform
% in the correct location for each pulse.
X = ifft( ifftshift( bsxfun( @times, fftshift( fft( wfm, Nrcv ) ), ...
  exp( -1j * 2*pi * tgtdelay(:) * f ) ), 2 ), [], 2 );

% Add the phase to the received waveforms.
X = bsxfun( @times, X, exp( -1j * 2*pi * f_c * tgtdelay(:) ) );

% Matched filter the received data.
Nfft = Nrcv + Nsamp - 1;
Y = ifft( fft( X, Nfft, 2 ) .* conj( fft( wfm, Nfft ) ), [], 2 );
Y = Y(:,1:Nrcv);

% Fourier transform acoss pulses to get Doppler.
Z = fftshift( fft( Y, [], 1 ), 1 );

% Display the range Doppler image.
d = ( 0 : Npulse - 1 ) / Npulse / pri;
d = d - dcsample(d);
imagesc( trcv*c0/2, d, abs( Z ) );

